# Mov data from my /var/www to another drive using terminal in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, ati, data-recovery

I can't uninstall ATI catalyst driver or due to some other issue i am getting blank screen in Ubuntu 12.04 .
I am able to access terminal and data in recovery mode. So how can i move the data from my /var/www to some other drives so that i can access it in my windows.

Please help me out, i have a lot of data i have been working upon for last six months

Comment: Boot from a live session and copy your data to the windows partition directly from www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to mount the other device where you want to move the data.
This can be done by using the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/newdrive
```

After making a "newdrive" folder in /media/

you can mount your drive by:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newdrive
```

(/dev/sdb1 is the drive you want to mount and newdrive is the newly created folder)

After the drive has been mounted, move the directory by using these commands:

```
sudo mv /path/to/source /path/to/dest
```

In your case it will be something like:

```
sudo mv /var/www /media/newdrive
```

Remember to mount the drive to newdrive first. And if it is already mounted skip the first two steps.

Comment: i know about /dev/sdb1 that it is internal hard drive   but i have no idea about /media ...   Can you please explain it what is media , is it external pen drive

Comment: /media is any directory on your hard dist. "/media/newdrive" is only a logical mount-point for your actual physical drive. So, in fact, you could choose to mount the sdb at any location of your choice which is not used. (P.s.: /media is often chosen as ubuntu or any linux does not put any of its own file in it, hence it is always guaranteed to be empty, unless you put something there.)

Comment: Must mention that it's a good idea to mount the volume at boot by making an entry in `fstab`. I'd have recommended a slightly different approach though - `sudo cp -pdR /var/www ~/www` then `sudo rm -rf /var/www` then `sudo mkdir /var/www` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www` then make entry in `fstab` and finally `sudo cp -pdR ~/www /var/.`. Check permissions/ownership/disk-usage with `sudo ls -al /var/www` and `df -h`. Cheers!